# R: how to find the indices of the maximal value per column

Tags: r, indexing

Given this matrix

```
mat

     [,1] [,2] [,3]

[1,]    1    2    3

[2,]    7    8    1

[3,]    4    5    6
```

I want to find the maximum value in all columns plus their indices (row number). So basically, I need the following information:

```
max = [7 8 6]
ind = [2 2 3]
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transpose `mat` and use `max.col`

```
i = max.col(t(mat))
v = t(mat)[cbind(seq(NCOL(mat)), i)]
v
# [1] 7 8 6
i
# [1] 2 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply` to loop over the columns (`MARGIN = 2`), get the `max` and the index of max (`which.max`) in a named `vector` as output

```
apply(mat, 2, function(x) c(max = max(x), ind = which.max(x)))
```

-output

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
max    7    8    6
ind    2    2    3
```

---

Or another option is [`colMaxs`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpgm/versions/1.1.2/topics/colMaxs%20-%20rowMaxs%20-%20colMins%20-%20rowMins) and [`max.col`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/maxCol)

```
library(matrixStats)
colMaxs(mat)
#[1] 7 8 6
max.col(t(mat))
#[1] 2 2 3
```

#### data

```
mat <- structure(c(1, 7, 4, 2, 8, 5, 3, 1, 6), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
```